# How can I retrieve values from a Python z3 solver model

Tags: python, string, list, z3, z3py

I have created a z3 solver model on Python to solve a system of equations.

```
s = solver.model()
```

`s` gives

```
[X_429_1_W =
-434458038280884901310630135009228057/500000000000000000000000000000000000, X_306_1 = 0, X_182_1 = 38029185943162404721169362934156969/312500000000000000000000000000000000, X_204_1_W = 51251520345945618230564656568799351/50000000000000000000000000000000000, X_297_1_W =
-266620360395040535630581298823392441/500000000000000000000000000000000000, X_367_1 = 1458894434043130767516483768551244821/2000000000000000000000000000000000000, X_687_0 = 0, X_359_1 = 0, X_548_0 = 4960784316062927/5000000000000000, X_24_1 = 569840368525122645412467087507866123/500000000000000000000000000000000000, X_344_1 = 0, X_101_0 = 0, X_313_1_W =
-21190064831365671661264827915943039/50000000000000000000000000000000000 ...
```

`type(s)` gives `z3.z3.ModelRef`

I want to find the value for a specific variable, say `X_182_1`. How can I do it ?

Edit:

This is the function I am using to solve a system of equations.

```
def my_eval(equations):
    var=[]
    solver = Solver()
    k=0
    for i in range(len(equations)):
        if equations[i].split()[0].startswith('X'):
          init_exec=f"{equations[i].split()[0]} = Real('{equations[i].split()[0]}')"

          exec(init_exec)
          k=k+1
          init_exec=f"{equations[i].split()[0][:-2]} = Real('{equations[i].split()[0][:-2]}')"
          exec(init_exec)
          k=k+1
        eqn_exec=f'solver.add({equations[i]})'
        exec(eqn_exec)
    
    solver.check()
    m=solver.model()
    return m
```

The model returned by the function displays the required values on `solver.model()` as given above but I am unable to extract the values of the individual variables.

The error thrown is

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-cdc645f3dd0b> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 solver_model[X_307_1_W]

NameError: name 'X_307_1_W' is not defined
```

Comment: Either keep track of your variables explicitly; or you can extract them from the model itself. See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In general, to get the values you simply index into the model, like this:

```py
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

X_429_1_W = Real('X_429_1_W');
s.add(X_429_1_W == Q(-434458038280884901310630135009228057,500000000000000000000000000000000000))
print(s.check())
m = s.model()
print(m)
print(m[X_429_1_W])
```

This prints:

```
sat
[X_429_1_W = -434458038280884901310630135009228057/500000000000000000000000000000000000]
-434458038280884901310630135009228057/500000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Of course, this requires you to know what the variables are. Looks like you have some sort of a loop where you "extract" the variables. You should keep them in a data-structure yourself, so you can refer to them later. Or, you can simply grab them from the model, with something like:

```py
m = s.model()
for var in m:
    print("Var: ", var, "Value:", m[var])
```